# Can JDT find org.eclipse.jdt.core.IMethod by java.lang.reflect.Method? Are there any related utilities?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

i did this

```java
IType class Element = .... ;
String name = ... ;
String[] parameterTypeSignatures = ... ;
classElement.getMethod(name, parameterTypeSignatures) ;
```

When I have a java.lang.reflect.Method object, I need to convert it to name and parameterTypeSignatures

I wrote the conversion rules by referring to the code of JDT

JDT Is there any practical tool that can directly use the internal reflection type of java.lang.reflect to search?

Comment: I don't understand your question (what do you mean by _"internal reflection type"_?). Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code where you are stuck.